# How to format the text box of excel to change the font style,size,name using c#,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

//Here is the sample code..

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
```

//creating shape object...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape[] myShapes = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape[1];
```

//creating rectangle shape

```
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 47, 24, 500, 90);
```

//adding text box

```
myShapes[0] = xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 75, 64,60, 30);
            myShapes[0].TextFrame.Characters(misValue, misValue).Text = "simple text";
            myShapes[0].Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            myShapes[0].Select(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `myShapes[0].TextFrame2.TextRange.Font = 12`

Answer (score 0):

This is how your add a shape and format it using Interop.

```
Shape sh = myWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture("...\\Images\\test.png",
                                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
                                    603,116, 162, 221); // Set Left,Top,Width, height
    sh.Placement = XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating;
    sh.TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Insert("This is sample text !!");
                        sh.TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Font.Size = 13;
    sh.TextFrame.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal;
    sh.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
    sh.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
    sh.TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Font.ColorIndex = 2;
    sh.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

    int titleBg = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(51, 204, 204));
    sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = titleBg;
    sh.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 41;
    sh.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```